# How to show support for questions when you're new?

Tags: discussion

I just found myself having this exact same problem: [Pods error trying to build Expo managed workflow app on SDK 45 using EAS build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72200966/pods-error-trying-to-build-expo-managed-workflow-app-on-sdk-45-using-eas-build)

Even though I didn't know how to answer the question (I was going to ask myself), I felt like it was my responsibility to show support. You know, just to increase visibility of the question, or to reassure the OP that other people were experiencing the same issue so they didn't feel alone.

However, because I'm new and don't have any reputation yet, I wasn't able to up-vote the question, nor to leave a comment, and I didn't have the answer either.

In the end, I felt hopeless and decided to ask here if you guys have any tips for new users who have duplicate questions that haven't been answered, to increase visibility or show support for those questions?

PS: I know the obvious answer is to earn reputation myself, but I don't have any other questions at the moment, and I don't feel ready to answer complex questions (since all "easy" questions most likely already have an answer).

Comment: If the question you found has no meaningful answers, and if you have the same question, ask your question, linking to the original and saying how it's different

Comment: Given the question was asked today, just wait. It's been asked, and is still active. It appears as though at least 5 others have had this same problem within the past few hours.

Comment: Heck, it's answered. In what way did the answer not explain why it's happening?

Comment: You can earn reputation by suggesting quality edits to existing posts.

Comment: Agreed @snakecharmerb, and it only takes 7 quality edits being approved to reach the 15 rep needed to upvote.  Please do make sure, though, that they are quality edits and attempt to fix *all* the problems you see with an answer or question.  Thanks!

Comment: It's really annoying, but because the Internet is a wretched hive of scum and villainy little hurdles like this are needed to SO clean (well cleaner) of casual spammers and vote fraudsters.

Comment: I'm hoping one day that SO does indeed give new users with no rep a way to provide feedback by some measurable means, even if it isn't a visible artifact such as a vote. Such users, along with the many many unregistered users, are indirectly the life blood of what keeps this site going. It's a shame SO can't take advantage of those metrics more and use them to possibly improve the site.

Answer (score 10):

To support the question, users can:

- Bookmark the question (no reps, does not really affect the asker other than adding the counter up)
- [Upvote the question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) (15 rep)
- [Discuss it in a chat room](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat) (20 rep)
- [Put a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) (75 rep and the question being at least 2 days old)

Unfortunately, for new users with 1 rep, there is nothing else they can do *on the site directly*.

Please note that **posting a comment (or, worse, an answer) with "I have the same problem" and nothing more is just noise, and it will be cleaned up sooner or later by the community or moderators.** The same as suggesting an edit to add "I have the same problem", it will be rejected since it is not the purpose of editing.

However, *users can always share the question on external sites* to give the question more attention.

Comment: You can also follow the question, which will alert you when new answers (or comments) are posted. If you have enough rep by then you can upvote them.